# arcpy SearchCursor is creating a comma within a tuple

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am creating a list of tuples of coordinates of a feature class.

Feature class is created as such:

```
inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```

The inFC is a point feature class.

I then have the following code to get the coordinates of all points in the feature class:

```
field = ['SHAPE@XY']
coordsList = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        coordsList.append(row)
```

I was expecting an output of a list of tuples as below;

```
[(250000, 230000), (234567, 2859340)...]
```

However instead I am getting a list of tuples of a tuple and a commma, as below:

```
[((251075.0, 237048.0),), ((250687.0, 236717.0),),...]
```

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: What is the length of "row"?  Have you tried `coordsList.append(row[0])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  Each row is returned as a tuple of field values, as stated in the [help docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000).  When you use the `SHAPE@XY`, it returns a tuple of the coordinates.  If you only have one field and want to make a list of your xy tuples, As Vince mentioned you'll have to get by index:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@XY']) as rows:
    coordList = [r[0] for r in rows]
```